# Python: Convert entire column to dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am just getting started with pandas recently.

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
locations=pd.read_csv('locations.csv')


   lat    lon
0 30.29 -87.44 
1 30.21 -87.44 
2 31.25 -87.41
```

I want to convert it to something like this

`{'lat': [37.974508, 38.050247, 37.985352],
 'lon': [-87.582584, -87.540012, -87.50776]}`

Answer (score 5):

Check `to_dict`

```
df.to_dict('l')
Out[951]: {'Lon': [-87.44, -87.44, -87.41], 'lat': [30.29, 30.21, 31.25]}
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this existed

Comment: Funny thing is that it only checks if `orient` argument starts with `'l'` [[source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a00154dcfe5057cb3fd86653172e74b6893e337d/pandas/core/frame.py#L987-L988)].  You could also use `df.to_dict('lazers')`

Answer (score 1):

Keys are column names, values are lists of column data

```
locations.to_dict('list')
```

Comment: We posted it simultaneously, it wasn't meant to be copied @piRSquared

Comment: Fair enough (-:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`lat_lon = {'lat': list(locations['lat']), 'lon': list(locations['lon'])}`